# Sphinx restructuredText to HTML hyperlink conversion

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a collection of reStructuredText files which link to each other in the following manner:

```
further reading at `document name <otherdoc.rst>`.
```

I have noticed that this works really well on BitBucket and Github, as .rst files are rendered quite nicely and the links in-between the files work.

However, now I wanted to generate HTML documents with Sphinx and noticed that Sphinx is not converting links like the example above to HTML links, so I have a bunch of HTML files with broken links. How can I fix this without breaking the links on GitHub and BitBucket?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Sphinx documentation on hyperlinks](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#hyperlinks) it seems that the syntax for inline external hyperlinks is

```
`Link text <http://example.com/>`_
```

Note the trailing `_` just after the final back-tick. Try adding this underscore and seeing if this fixes your links in your Sphinx output.